# Wallaby integration tests pass individually, fail when run together

Tags: elixir, integration-testing

I'm using [Wallaby](https://github.com/keathley/wallaby) (0.17.0) for acceptance tests with phantomjs (2.1.1), and the latest Elixir (1.4.5) and Erlang (20). I've written [a few acceptance tests](https://github.com/stevegrossi/habits/tree/f79d8b35bea5eb2ca24a88550f27012c08a4c6bf/test/acceptance), each of which passes when run individually, but when I run them together (via `mix test test/acceptance`) they fail because things that should be on the page aren't. It's as if all the tests are running in the same browser, even though Wallaby should "manage multiple browsers for you."

I believe I've set everything up according to [the setup section of the README](https://github.com/keathley/wallaby/blob/master/README.md#setup), although I'm not running the tests with `async: true` because my app uses sockets and `Phoenix.Ecto.SQL.Sandbox` [doesn't play well with async](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_ecto/issues/72). To be clear, the tests also fail with `async: true`, I just also get `DBConnection.OwnershipError`s in each when attempting to connect to the socket.

Is there anything else necessary to ensure each test is run in its own phantomjs browser, or to clear out sessions between test runs?

Comment: Does this help any? https://github.com/keathley/wallaby/issues/174

Comment: It might be helpful if you could show us some of your tests. `async: true` or not shouldn't effect elements being rendered on the page in Phantom.

PS: FWIW, `Phoenix.Ecto.SQL.Sandbox` plays very well with async, but when you couple it with acceptance tests you just very likely need to increase the ownership timeout which defaults to 15 seconds.

Comment: I ended up reproducing this in a sample app and opening an issue. I believe it's just a bug with Wallaby: https://github.com/keathley/wallaby/issues/274